# Bootstrap dropdown disappear with right-click on Firefox

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have some kind of problem with twitter-bootstrap and firefox.
I have a button and a dropdown menu with an input text. If I right click on the input ( for right-click + Paste for example), firefox closes the dropdown. And that quite boring.

Is there any solution for prevent that behaviour ?

Thanks !

Comment: Interesting. It seems the recent switch to delegate Bootstrap plugins' click listeners to the `$(document)` instead of `$('body')` has a negative side effect.  FF does not propagate a **click** event through the `<body>` for right-clicks, but does propagate one through `document`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an immediate stop-gap workaround you can use something along the following lines to prevent the **click** event from propagating when the click event is a right-click

### JS

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  e.button === 2 && e.stopImmediatePropagation()
})
```

This would need to be placed between **jQuery** loading and **Bootstrap** loading.

### [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wq1B46zhuW1wrGMoEr1E?p=preview)

However, this is a rather blunt approach and you'd probably be better off doing something more subtle if possible.

---

## Update

One way to circumvent this issue in a more targeted manner is to disable the original event listener and replace it with one that checks for right-clicks first.

### JS

```
// obtain a reference to the original handler
var _clearMenus = $._data(document, "events").click.filter(function (el) {
    return el.namespace === 'data-api.dropdown' && el.selector === undefined
  })[0].handler;

// disable the old listener
$(document)
  .off('click.data-api.dropdown', _clearMenus)
  .on('click.data-api.dropdown', function (e) {
    // call the handler only when not right-click
    e.button === 2 || _clearMenus()
  })
```

Unlike the previous example, this code would need to run *after* Bootstrap has loaded.

### [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/I9lcwmVaRqmGRaBCfuMS?p=preview)

Comment: This is a very useful fix awaiting an official response from Bootstrap team. I opened an issue on their Github, I will put eventual evolution here.
Thank you for the quick response and the quality ! Cheers !

Comment: Ok it seems that this is an official issue (they have a problem with middle click too).

Comment: this is still not working in firefox if you have dropdowns opening on hover - check http://plnkr.co/edit/Dc3Hg185Vs0lR7gdohnZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

For **Bootstrap 3** you have to update the namespace to `bs.data-api.dropdown`.

### JS

```
// obtain a reference to the original handler
var _clearMenus = $._data(document, "events").click.filter(function (el) {
  return el.namespace === 'bs.data-api.dropdown' && el.selector === undefined
})[0].handler;

// disable the old listener
$(document)
  .off('click.data-api.dropdown', _clearMenus)
  .on('click.data-api.dropdown', function (e) {
    // call the handler only when not right-click
    e.button === 2 || _clearMenus()
  })
```

### [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PKnPcQ5YcCQJDyw0ijPx?p=preview)