# Bootstrap 3.0 avoid dropdown closing on right-click in FF

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am still unsuccessful in getting bootstrap 3.0 dropdowns to work as a dropdown should in Firefox. Right clicking a link inside the dropdown in order to open it in a new tab closes the dropdown in FF but works as it should in Chrome and IE. This seems to be an unresolved bug in Bootstrap which has been around for a long time -see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar for a demo. The workaround I have managed below is not satisfactory since it requires toggling the dropdown-toggle link to close the dropdown again, while ideally it should close on a mouse click anywhere outside the dropdown.

```
<div id="fixed-menu"> 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div#fixed-menu li.dropdown > a.dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but there is an answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931962/bootstrap-dropdown-disappear-with-right-click-on-firefox

Comment: @AndreasFröwis Thank you for pointing me to a workaround fix to the problem, however I ended up giving up Bootstrap for Foundation, where everything works out of the box. IMO a much better framework.